# Activity Lifecycle. When application already opened (Collapsed) is closing and starting again on icon click?

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

Can you please explain to me why my activity which is currently (`onStop`) is go to `OnDestroy` event and restarting again after clicking on the app icon in the interface. 
Because of that i have problem with user data saving. I'm using event `OnDestroy` to ask user if he want to save the data. Because of my misunderstanding when i collapse the app and click to it again i am waiting to my activity to have all the data in it but instead  i see saving dialog from the previous activity whiсh goes to `onDestroy` event.
Other apps don't act like this.
What should i check?

Comment: Er....what is `this icon in the interface`? Maybe a screenshot would help.

Comment: The question is not clear!

Comment: The app icon in the interface. Sorry for that.

Comment: If your app is in background(In recent app list ) Then the OS can kill it in memory management cycle. Thats what happen when Os in need of more memory . Again starting the app will land you on your first screen.  OnDestroy() not guaranteed to call in scenario .

Comment: Probably you should try to use `onPause()` instead, `onDestroy()` is not guaranteed to be called

Comment: In my case onPause is calling later than user collapse the app.
Lets say i'm collapsing the app by home button and onPause event with save dialog appear 5-6 seconds later. I dont like this way.

Answer (score 0):

Your description is not very clear, so my answer may not help you.

Research the app life cycle here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html

Your app will enter onStop is before onDestroy. This can happen if user activates another app. (So the user may no longer see any prompts that you display e.g. To ask to save or not.) Android may choose to destroy your app based on its rules after that point, even if the user clicks on the app icon to start it again.

Perhaps you can test what happens if the user switches back to the app (not clicking the icon), but use the "Recent apps" button and select it.

Comment: if i call the app from recent app everything goes fine. I see my data, OnDestroy event is not calling. The same i want to acheave if user click the app icon. The thing i dont understand is why in this case it goes to onDestroy last activity and start a new one.

Comment: I think this is consistent with how Android works. It will only call onDestroy if it needs to (e.g. Free resources that is required for other apps or activities). Maybe Android thinks that because the user clicked the icon they want to restart the app. In that case it will destroy the previously running instance

Comment: on the other apps this is not reproducing.